# Document Size - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I am working in Illustrator from a document created by another designer. I'd like to use the info in this document but need to know what the size of the document is. How do you determine the document size in Illustrator? Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the file size in an explorer window.

If you have dimensions turned on you can see the pixel dimensions in explorer as well.

You can see the art board dimensions when you select the art board tool in illustrator.

You can see the resolution and dimensions under Window > Document Info.